# What is causing the multi-part join error in this SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been struggling with the sql and have tried a few approaches but can't get it working.

Can any SQL experts work out why this SQL is erroring, I think it's due to the `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT 
    t.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [owner_details].[id]) AS _row_num, 
         COUNT(count_column) 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 1 AS count_column 
          FROM [owner_details] 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies cur ON owner_details.currency_id = cur.id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN  primary_contacts as pc ON  owner_details.primary_contact_id = pc.id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON pc.contact_id = contacts.id 
          WHERE [owner_details].[primary_id] = 405062121) subquery_for_count) AS t 
WHERE 
    t._row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

I should note that this SQL is programmatically generated via an ORM in Ruby on Rails but if I can work out the issue with the SQL maybe I can figure out how to change my code.

I want to understand the SQL better.

The error:

> The multi-part identifier "owner_details.id" could not be bound..

Comment: `owner_details` is in a subquery, and cannot be accessed by the outer query; `owner_details.id` could be selected in the subquery, and the outer query could reference `subquery_for_count.id`. _Also.... MySQL <> MSSQLServer_

Comment: What is you are trying to achieve actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below using t.[id] in order by i have assumed you id column in `owner_details`

```
SELECT 
    t.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY subquery_for_count.[id]) AS _row_num, 
         COUNT(count_column) over()
     FROM 
         (SELECT 1 AS count_column,owner_details.id as id
          FROM [owner_details] 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies cur ON owner_details.currency_id = cur.id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN  primary_contacts as pc ON  owner_details.primary_contact_id = pc.id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON pc.contact_id = contacts.id 
          WHERE [owner_details].[primary_id] = 405062121
          ) subquery_for_count) AS t 
WHERE 
    t._row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Comment: Zaynul, You need only 1 sub-query.

Comment: The multi-part identifier "t.id" could not be bound.

Comment: @user3437721 edited my bad i used topest subquery name but it would be inner one please check now

Comment: hit this now `Column 'subquery_for_count.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @user3437721 have to use over clause for count()

Answer (score 0):

The [multi-part naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) conversion basically goes four levels (other than columns) in SQL. i.e.

1. Object (Table, view, stored procedure etc..)
2. Schema (schema name, default 'dbo')
3. Database (Database name)
4. Server (Server name, particularly when querying linked servers)

In your case `[owner_details]` is considered as table in sub-query, and as schema in `OVER` clause. Aside from this since you add alias name to sub-query (`subquery_for_count`), you should call it as `subquery_for_count.id` (in `OVER` clause)

Full query must go as:

```
SELECT 
    t.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY subquery_for_count.[id]) AS _row_num, 
         COUNT(count_column) as CountCoumn
     FROM 
         (SELECT 1 AS count_column, owner_details.id as id
          FROM  [owner_details] 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies cur ON owner_details.currency_id = cur.id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  primary_contacts as pc ON  owner_details.primary_contact_id = pc.id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON pc.contact_id = contacts.id 
          WHERE [owner_details].[primary_id] = 405062121
          ) subquery_for_count
     GROUP BY subquery_for_count.[id]
    ) AS t 
WHERE 
    t._row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```